# Menu item hover effects and sublist hovering

Tags: jquery, list, menu, hover

I have problem with menu item hover effects.

At first, I have four images here:
http://www.upload.ee/image/3408064/abi.png

It is wordpress site and this menu is generated and managed by wordpress menus.

In first image, you can see menu in left side.
Grey uppercase items are main items and by clicking them appears sublist with blue text and white background.

hovering sublist item will act like in second image (another sublist appears)

Here comes the problematic part. When i move cursor to appearing sublist, parent item hover effect dissapears, like in third image.

I want the parent hover effect to stay, when i move to sublist.
Like in last image...

Here is my current script for sublist apperaing while hovering parent sublist item:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.left-sidebar li li').hover(function () {
        jQuery(this).children('ul').slideDown(1);
    }, function () {
        jQuery(this).children('ul').fadeOut(1);
    });
});
```

and here is main item click action script for first submenu appearence:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.left-sidebar li').click(function () {
        jQuery(this).children('ul').slideDown(300);
    }
});
```

Here is jsfiddle: [jsfiddle.net/TBRgu](http://jsfiddle.net/TBRgu/) Some background styles are missing, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: Looks like your submenu is child of menu. Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: check this link.. http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical

Comment: I'll look at the link, seems helpful. I forgot to add, it is wordpress site and this menu is generated and managed by wordpress menus.

Comment: Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TBRgu/

Some background styles are missing, but it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TBRgu/2/

Change this:

```
.left-sidebar .box  li li a:hover
```

To this:

```
.left-sidebar #menu-kutsemeistrivoistlused > li > ul > li:hover > a
```

Change the width as below:

```
.left-sidebar .box  li li li a{
    background: none;
    padding-left: 4px;
    width: 186px; /* changed from 165px */
    border:0;
}
```